# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Above error along with these errors and cannot resolve R symbol error.

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request.
```

Check logs for details.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request.
```

Check logs for details.

I tried all solutions given like rebuild,invalidate caches and restart, changed dependencies as well and clean project did not used any images. I installed android studio 3.0.1 in ubuntu 14.04 OS type 32-bit

Is this a installed android stdio version mistake please help me out.

Comment: This error annoyed me and mostly reason was I had some resources named inappropriate (spacing, special characters, etc). Had some string.xml conflicts or any other resource files (dimen, values etc). Sadist part is android studio doesn't indicate it specifically.